# How to unittest file containing assert __name__ == "__main__"

Tags: unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I want to unit test a piece of code from a module using the Mock testing library.

```
# File_name: do.py

assert __name__ == "__main__", "This module should NOT be imported."

from disk import Disk

def bool_fun(args):
    res = Disk.disks()
    print(res)
    if args not in res:
        return -1
    return args
```

The above file contains **assert **name** == "__main__"** which is blocking the module from getting import in test file.

```
# File_name: do_test.py

import unittest
from unittest import mock

import do

class DOTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('do.Disk.disks')
    def test_bool_fun(self, mock_disks):
        args = 4
        mock_disks.return_value = [4,3,2,3,4]
        res = do.bool_fun(args)
        self.assertEqual(res, args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

One more helper file which is imported in **do.py** file,

```
# File_name: disk.py
import random

class Disk():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def disks():
        lis = []
        for i in range(5):
            lis.append(random.randint(1,10))
        return lis
```

Assuming all files are kept in the same directory, I'm getting below error when trying to test it.

```
    assert __name__ == "__main__", "This module should NOT be imported."
AssertionError: This module should NOT be imported.
```

However, it works great if I remove the **assert** code from **do.py** file.

Can you please tell me how to test such files containing **assert **name** == "__main__"** in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a lot of research and following over 100+ Stackoverflow links I can not find a solution that can straight away help in importing the file to UT.

**Reason**

You can mock the assert or the **name** because it hasn't been imported yet. You have to import it to assert, which won't work because you'll hit the exception.

**Solution**

So a hacky way, which should be OK since this is a UT, is to do an os.system call to "sed -i '/assert __name__/d' path/to/file" before importing it. That will just remove the line from the file at the run time :)

**Example**

```
import os
os.system("sed -i '/assert __name__/d' /path/to/file")
```